# Why are certain kosher meat / poultry parts hard to obtain in the U.S.?

Tags: chutz-laaretz, meat, parts-of-the-body

Years ago, my parents could easily purchase these meat & poultry parts that I rarely see now:

- chicken feet
- cow / calf lungs
- goose & goose liver

When I was in Israel, these animals or parts seemed easily obtainable, but I can't find it in the U.S.:

- goat meat
- "Rocky Mountain Oysters" (a.k.a. - bull "nuts")

Venison is kosher, and a few restaurants serve it, but I've never seen it in butcher stores.

Why are these, esp. the top few items that WERE once obtainable, difficult to find?

Comment: Low demand. [15]

Comment: @DoubleAA - possibly, but not a correlation. Many people may not know about it b/c it hasn't been sold in a while.

Comment: I have seen chicken feet in Pomegranate in Brooklyn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because according to the top voted answer on meta: meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3747/8775 an answer is on topic "But in general, I think a question is in scope here if it passes the tests, "Does it matter whether this is Jewish?" and "Would this get [roughly] the same answer on another SE site as here?" The question as phrased by the OP dos not seem to satisfy this criterion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The question is not if there is an Halachic problem which lead to difficulty to find these products, but a question about a commercial phenomenon.

Comment: @kouty If you think that questions like this should be off-topic, consider expressing your opinion on the related [meta post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/262/the-parameters-of-jewish-life-scope). Perhaps consider looking at my answers: [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4077/8775) and [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4076/8775).

Comment: @sabbahillel If you think that questions like this should be off-topic, consider expressing your opinion on the related [meta post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/262/the-parameters-of-jewish-life-scope). Perhaps consider looking at my answers: [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4077/8775) and [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4076/8775).

Comment: @mbloch If you think that questions like this should be off-topic, consider expressing your opinion on the related [meta post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/262/the-parameters-of-jewish-life-scope). Perhaps consider looking at my answers: [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4077/8775) and [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4076/8775).

Answer (score 2):

There were certain intestines that were taken off the market by the F.D.A. along with animal feet. After reappearing on the market when regulations were laxed, the new generation simply had no interest. Especially if they are expensive and no longer on the taste pallet of your average person. 
As far as Rocky Mountain Oysters, all parts from the hind quarters are not eaten by popular Ashkenazi tradition of not 'treibering', removal of forbidden veins and fats, nikur in halachic talk. Some Sfardim in Israel still continue their tradition and remove what is assur and enjoy the rest.

EDIT. Turns out testicles do in fact require a certain type of nikur, to remove blood vessels. See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah siman 65 siff 4.

Comment: Mountain Fruit sells chicken feet.

Comment: [Editing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/44026/edit) any source for your information would improve your answer.

Comment: But testicles don't require Nikkur. (Not entirely true, but compared to, say, a T-bone steak, it is _quite_ simple.)

Comment: @ msh sorry this is all mipi hashmua. @Aa True. Neither do tails. But the entire hind is unused by Ashkenazim.

Comment: @DoubleAA The way it was explained to me by someone from the Star K is that in order to be able to avoid the extra expense of treibering, the entire rear half of the animal is cut off and shipped to the nonkosher side. It would not pay to cut some parts for specialty items.

Comment: @sabbahillel Again, that may be true for a T-bone steak which is inside the animal. Removing the scrotum would take 3 seconds. Cost is definitely not the issue here.

Comment: @DoubleAA Quite true, but it would have to be kept with the original carcase, and there would be paper work and other matters. The way it was explained to me was that it is just easier to just ship it over and not do anything else.

Comment: @user6591 (from google search)  [kosher oxtail](http://www.kolfoods.com/oxtail.asp) with an [OU for Ashkenazim](http://www.kolfoods.com/certifications-and-shechita.asp)

Comment: ?????? "[But testicles don't require Nikkur. (**Not entirely true, but compared to, say, a T-bone steak, it is quite simple**.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44024/why-are-certain-kosher-meat-poultry-parts-hard-to-obtain-in-the-u-s/45083#comment114696_44026)" (emphasis added) I'm well aware of what needs to be done and have seen it done personally. Your edit seems out of place. I move for rolling it back.

Comment: "popular Ashkenazi tradition of not 'treibering'" No such tradition exists at all.

Comment: You've had tenderloin?

Comment: I reworded the edit. Hope its less offensive to you.

Comment: @user6591 I have. It was scrumptious.

Comment: Mayim ginuvim are sweet:) Unless it was in israel where they still treibur?

Comment: @user6591 I watched the Shechita, Bedika and Nikkur myself, and spoke to the Shocheit/Bodeik/Menaker about the relevant Halachot. I am confident it was Kosher leMehadrin. (And it wasn't ginuvim because I paid for it!)

Answer (score 0):

The sale of lungs is illegal in the U.S.

the rest of your items there is no market (so it is very expensive)in the US for them
(goat meat is starting to get popular again)

if you will search you will be able to special order these items

PS @user6591's answer 
the treibering of the testicles is because of blood (and not becouse of fats), Ashkenazim have a tradition on how it is done on the testicles even in America

Comment: True. My point wasn't to say why its impossible, just why its not worth the time and energy.

Comment: Ashkenazim have traditions about the fat parts too. It's just not worth it economically.

Comment: In America the tradition is NOT to treiber (for sale, I heard or an allowance for personal use) the meat of the carcass from in the front the navel and the 13th rib (including) until in the back the 3rd vertebra of the tail (including) and the toes (not including)

Comment: @shmuel That is generally current practice. It's definitely not a tradition of binding import. What does that have to do with Ashkenazim? The OU supervises Nikkur on deer even today!

Comment: @DoubleAA I heard it was decreed in America (so that the money and laziness will not trip Jews with forbidden fats), yes I am wrong it is with the exception of wild animals (I.E. Deer) and birds

Comment: @shmuel What you heard is a common misconception http://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_nikkur_achoraim/ "the exception of birds" ??? Birds have nothing to treiber.

Comment: @DoubleAA Treibering of birds, remove or cut the blood vessels in the neck, cut off the toe nails, (remove the inner organs for salting)

Comment: Wow. DoubleAa I'm surprised at you. Comparing deer to cattle in respects to nikur of cheilev?

Comment: @user6591 No. Nikkur of Gid HaNasheh.

Comment: @shmuel Oh. I didn't even think that would be a question that you need to exclude it (not that there is anything it is excluded from. As stated above there is no minhag against treibering anything.)

Comment: Ah. gotcha. I definitely heard the word minhag used by Rabbi Belsky in respect to not treiburing.